# Reverse and invert binary matrix using one list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

I have matrix `A` and made code to reverse and invert it (added some print to show how matrix looks like after each step).

Code:

```
A = [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]
print(A)
# First step: reverse each row. So, for example, first row from 1,1,0 became 0,1,1
A = [x[::-1] for x in A]
print("Matrix after reverse each row:")
print(A)
# Second step: inverse. Replace each 1 with 0 and 0 with 1. So 0,1,1 will be 1,0,0
A = [[1-y for y in x] for x in A]
print("Matrix after invert")
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
Matrix after reverse each row:
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
Matrix after invert
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Can I create one single list comprehension from two steps in a code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another for loop looping over the sublists in your list comprehension. Here `for j in x[::-1]` will loop over the elements of each sublists and `1-j` will give you what you want.

```
A = [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]

A = [[1-j for j in x[::-1]] for x in A]
print (A)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I want)